# Gone to practice or gone for practice

Tags: word-usage

A few children are practicing marching.  So everyone in my school knows this and we call it "practice". So where the context is obvious, what would sound natural:

> She's gone **to/for** practice.

What sounds natural here "to/for"?

Answer (score 1):

This would normally be "She's gone to practice" or "She's gone for marching practice"  or a few other variations, so either 'to' or 'for' can be used in very similar ways.

A slightly closer version of yours, using for: "She's gone for some practice."

Comment: For another example, saying, "she's left **for** practice."

Comment: Or *she's **at** practice* or even *she's* ***practising***.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if it's for an organised practise session, it would be **for**

> She's gone for practise

The unspoken [Marching/Band/Piano] unnecessary if it's obvious which one it is (because it's organised / regular / etc)

If she's just gone to do a bit of practising on her own though, then **to**

> She's gone to practise

Here, she might have gone to her room to practise some moves (or playing a flute or whatever she is practising)

(BTW - Practise is the UK spelling)